# Can't make my activity appear in the toolbar (WWF)

Tags: workflow, foundation

I'm using Windows Workflow Fundation and I can not make my new activity appear in the toolbox in order to use it in my workflow.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you expect to happen? What happens instead? If you provide this information in your question, people will be able to help you much more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clean and build solution. If it is correct will work